# VLCJ - playing a rtsp stream video in eclipse, but not after make executable JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, stream, rtsp, vlcj

I have a rtsp stream client application. It takes rtsp stream address from cam1.bin file and works fine in eclipse, but after export to executable JAR there is a problem. Probably with absolutepath, I geuss so. I've tried many ways to fix this by absolutepath, but no result.

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setLocation(100,100);
f.setSize(1200,720);    
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   
f.setVisible(true); 
//f.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
f.setTitle("rtsp app");

Canvas c = new Canvas();
c.setBackground(Color.black);
JPanel p = new JPanel();
p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

p.add(c);
f.add(p);


NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(),"lib");
Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);

MediaPlayerFactory mpf = new MediaPlayerFactory();
EmbeddedMediaPlayer emp = mpf.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer(new Win32FullScreenStrategy(f));
emp.setVideoSurface(mpf.newVideoSurface(c));
//emp.toggleFullScreen();
emp.setEnableMouseInputHandling(false);
emp.setEnableKeyInputHandling(false);



try{
    DataInputStream strumien = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("cam1.bin"));
    
    String file= (strumien.readUTF()); 
            
    emp.prepareMedia(file);
    
    emp.play();
    
    strumien.close();   
} catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    System.out.println("File not found");
} catch(IOException e){
    System.out.println("OI error");
}
}
```

}

Any ideas, advice?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If `cam.bin` is in the jar you cannot read it with `FileInputStream`. Objects in a jar are not files and can't be read with File APIs. Look at Class.getResource, Class.getResourceAsStream

Comment: Hi. Cam.bin is a separate file. Other my app dedicated to read/write the rtsp address in this file has no problem to access to it. So the problem is to read in right way rtsp address after export the JAR file. Before, in eclipse ide it works absolutely fine.

Comment: Is "cam1.bin" in the same directory that you run your executable jar from? And when you say there's a "problem", what do you mean - an exception, if so, post the exception.

Comment: Yes, "cam1.bin" file is in the same directory (before jar export in project directory - then works ok, and after export in the same directory as jar file). Before export in ide is ok, but after export is only black background (as set in setBackground). There is no exception, because app see the file and reads it. In an earlier version of this program, when the address of rtsp stream was typed in the code, the problem was the same. In ide ok, but after export app didn't want to open the address (black background). That's why I wonder is the problem with interpretation of path. (lib in the dir).

Comment: When you create your MediaPlayerFactory, pass "-vvv" then study the native logs that are produced.